# How to add all input required information in one single gpg command line?

Tags: gnupg

GnuPG documentation is not that great for a beginner like me and I coudn't find much detailed information ouside either, I hope you can give me some guidance about this:

I am developing a wrapper for the `gpg` command line tool. I would like to know if I can fit on only one command line all the input information needed to generate a key pair.

Currently I have to call: `gpg --gen-key` and input several other pieces of information like the key type, expiration info, name, email, and comment one at a time.

I'm couldn't figure out the `gpg` manual to assist on this, any tips are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the answer can be found in this part of the manual: [Unattended GPG key generation](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Unattended-GPG-key-generation.html).

As an example:

```
cat <<EOF | gpg2 --batch --gen-key
Key-Type: DSA
Key-Length: 1024
Subkey-Type: ELG-E
Subkey-Length: 1024
Name-Real: Joe Tester
Name-Comment: with stupid passphrase
Name-Email: joe@foo.bar
Expire-Date: 20170115
Passphrase: abc
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

GnuPG 2.1.0 added the parameter `--quick-generate-key`, which allows creation of a new key with common options.

Slightly summarizing the [documentation](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/OpenPGP-Key-Management.html):

> --quick-generate-key user-id [algo [usage [expire]]]
>
> --quick-gen-key
>
> This is a simple command to generate a standard key with one user id. In contrast to --generate-key the key is generated directly without the need to answer a bunch of prompts.
>
> If algo or usage are given, only the primary key is created and no prompts are shown. To specify an expiration date but still create a primary and subkey use “default” or “future-default” for algo and “default” for usage.
>
> The expire argument can be used to specify an expiration date for the key. Several formats are supported; commonly the ISO formats “YYYY-MM-DD” or “YYYYMMDDThhmmss” are used. To make the key expire in N seconds, N days, N weeks, N months, or N years use “seconds=N”, “Nd”, “Nw”, “Nm”, or “Ny” respectively. Not specifying a value, or using “-” results in a key expiring in a reasonable default interval. The values “never”, “none” can be used for no expiration date.
>
> If this command is used with --batch, --pinentry-mode has been set to loopback, and one of the passphrase options (--passphrase, --passphrase-fd, or passphrase-file) is used, the supplied passphrase is used for the new key and the agent does not ask for it. To create a key without any protection --passphrase '' may be used.
>
> Note that it is possible to create a primary key and a subkey using non-default algorithms by using “default” and changing the default parameters using the option --default-new-key-algo.